# How do you build a model based on entries in a vector in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have this data frame:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Users = c(200L, 305L), Transactions = c(460, 702.4
), Workload = c(100, 109.9), HeapUsage = c(25, 35.83)), .Names = c("Users", 
"Transactions", "Workload", "HeapUsage"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

in Sniny:

I want to build a lm model like this:

```
lm.model <- reactive({

    df <- data_set()
    if (!is.null(df)){

      xv <- input$xaxisGrp
      yv <- input$yaxisGrp
      print(xv)
      print(yv)
      if (!is.null(xv) & !is.null(yv)){

        if (sum(xv %in% names(df))>0){ # supress error when changing files

          lm.model <- lm(as.formula(paste(yv, '~', xv)), data = df)
          return(lm.model)

        }
      }
    }
  })
```

This only assumes that xv has only one variable. How do I change this line if xv has multi variables in as Transactions, Workload, Users etc?

for example, It needs to do this:

```
lm(data=df, HeapUsage~Transactions+Workload+Users)
```

This is just an example xv variables may change depending on the uploaded data and column names. xv vector is a vector could have one or multiple variables in.

Comment: Something like `paste(xv, collapse="+")`?

Comment: I did that, it still picks up the first entry in xy vector.

Comment: You didn't mention that you didn't want the first entry in `xv`, but if desired, just do `xv[-1]`

Comment: sorry, that's not what I meant, I want the model to do this lm(yv~xv), when I use variables as above, it only picks up the first entry in xv vector to do the lm, not the others. It needs to be multi-variete.

Comment: Is it possible that your `xv` is not a vector? Otherwise it should work. See answer below.

Comment: @warmoverflow, I found the problem. I was referring to yv as xv. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with the `iris` dataset

```
xv <- colnames(iris)[-c(1,5)]
lm.model <- lm(data = iris, as.formula(paste('Sepal.Length', '~', paste(xv, collapse = '+'))))
```